# Reordering array based on precise values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to reorder an array of objects based on one of the nested object's string values. The array has to be in this order. My attempt works but seems like a bloated and possibly inefficient solution:

```
reorder(order) {
    // create array with 4 null positions
    var newOrder = [null, null, null, null];

    // order can have between 0 - 4 objects
    for(var x = 0; x < order.length; x++){

        // based on value, assign predefined positions
        switch (order[x].slug){
            case 'cheeseburger':
                newOrder[0] = order[x];
                break;
            case 'salad':
                newOrder[1] = order[x];
                break;
            case 'fries':
                newOrder[2] = order[x];
                break;
            case 'iceCream':
                newOrder[3] = order[x];
                break;
        }
    }
    console.log(newOrder);
    return newOrder;
}
```

How can I reorder the array without creating the null positions?

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/jashoop/pen/wdqYbO?editors=1112#)

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve] - for example what is `order` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// assume you have the data arr
var arr = [{
  slug: 'cheeseburger'
}, {
  slug: 'salad'
}, {
  slug: 'fries'
}];

function reorder(arr){
// instead of switch, we put the order into an object
var slugOrder = {
  cheeseburger: 0,
  salad: 1,
  fries: 2
};

// with the native sort function you can get expected results
return arr.sort(function(itemA, itemB) {
  return slugOrder[itemA] - slugOrder[itemB]
});
}
console.log(reorder(arr));
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a real example - for example array.sort ALSO  sorts the array in situ so no need to return it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom comparison function for use with `.sort()`.

Described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Building on Sabrina's answer:

```
var aMenu = [
 {'name':'A','slug':'salad'},
 {'name':'B','slug':'cheeseburger'},
 {'name':'C','slug':'fries'}];
var oSlugOrder = {'cheeseburger':0,'salad':1,'fries':2};
aMenu.sort(function(oItemA, oItemB){
 return oSlugOrder[oItemA.slug] - oSlugOrder[oItemB.slug]; });
```

Comment: That is a comment. Add the relevant code to make it an answer and your rep will be increased to more than the 50 you need to be allowed to comment